# How I can append for loop range(500, 1000)

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, append

I wrote the following code:

```
for i in range(500, 1000):
    result = []   
    result.append(i)
```

That gives me `result = [999]`

But I want to get `result = [500, 501, 502.... 999]`

How can I fix to get result what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Try that with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
result = [i for i in range(500, 1000)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result = []
for i in range(500, 1000):
    result.append(i)
```

Comment: You basically need to delcare the list result outside the loop.

Comment: Put that 'comment' in your answer since it's part of the answer maybe?

Comment: OK i will follow your reccomandation ;-), but if the answer now works, you should accept it!

Comment: I am not OP, just someone passing by

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting `result` in each loop step. Don't to this.

Create the list with `list`:

```
result = list(range(500, 1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code only show 999, because you make empty `result` every looping and you will get last value. So you must change make initial `result` before loop.

The code is already given by another. This the code :

```
result = []
for i in range(500,1000):
    result.append(i)
```